# How to batch copy-paste images with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to copy an image and paste it to another one, and do it with all the images in a folder of 500 images.

When I run this code nothing happens.

I put an Image.show() to see what's happening, and when I run it the following error appears: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'show'
"

```
from PIL import Image
import os 

f = r'C:\Users\Utente-XB\Desktop\img\imgResized\New folder' 
Layout_image = Image.open("Portada-blanco.jpg")
area = (120, 200, 470, 550)
for file in os.listdir(f): 
       f_img = f+"/"+file
       im = Image.open(f_img)
       im2 = imgFondo.paste(im, (120, 200, 470, 550))
       im2.show()
       im2.save(f_img)
```

Comment: @RichieV that doesn't address the errors in the code posted - it shows how to paste correctly, but not how to save correctly.

Comment: @RandomDavis It does answer the main request from OP, any further problems are secondary and are more reason for this question to be closed because it lacks focus

Comment: I edited the question, now is focused. And no, that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @user1195523 did my answer help?

Comment: Yes @RandomDavis your answer was useful to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PIL's `Image.paste()` function accepts an image as its input, not a file path. Here's how it should be used in your code:

```
im = Image.open(f_img)
New_img = Layout_image.paste(im, area)
```

Additionally, PIL's `Image.save()` function accepts a file path as its input, not an Image - you have to call `.save()` on the Image itself:

```
New_img.save(f_img) # Use the path f_img or whichever one you want
```